# Sorting with stochastic comparisions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, probability

Given a list where for every pair of elements (A, B) the probabilities P(A > B), P(A < B), and P(A = B) is known, how do you determine the most probable sorted permutation?

Comment: That may end up being more of a math problem (http://math.stackexchange.com/) than a programming problem.

Comment: Is there any other knowledge known on the probabilities, like enforcing [transitive relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) of some kind?

Comment: Seems simple enough - sort the list with a comparison function that compares their probabilities instead of the items themselves. `bool Less(A, B) return P(A < B) > P(A > B)`

Comment: The simplest approach would be to use a search algorithm, such as A*. But there may be a more efficient solution here.

Comment: @MarkRansom That might not produce a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), i.e. `A > B`, `B > C` and `C > A` can all be more probable than their respective opposites, so you don't know how to order them.

Comment: How do you measure the probability of a given permutation?

Comment: FWIW, this is in some sense what rating systems like TrueSkill, Elo, and Glicko try to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's ignore `P(A=B)` (we can say it splits evenly among `<,>` and change them to `<=,>=`).

Now, let's look at a similar, yet intuitively easier problem:

- let's find the best assignment such that `P(arr[0]<arr[1])*...*P(arr[i]<arr[i+1])*...*P(arr[n-2]<arr[n-1])` is maximal.
- This is easier problem since we now take into account only adjacent elements, (and not for example `P(arr[0]<arr[n-1])` - we use 'less' information. [proof is missing atm].

Now, we are looking to maximize the probability, which is equivalent to maximizing:

```
log{P(arr[0]<arr[1])} + ... + log{P(arr[n-2]<arr[n-1])}
```

Which in its turn is equivalent to minimizing:

```
-log{P(arr[0]<arr[1])} - ... - log{P(arr[n-2]<arr[n-1])}
```

This is a [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with weights on edges:

```
w(v,u) = -log(P(v<u))
```

However, TSP is NP-Complete, and unless the missing proof hypothesis is wrong (still thinking on it...) - it means that there is no known polynomial solution to this problem, or at the very least to the adjacent elements only variation.

Comment: Is the adjacent elements formulation natural?  It doesn't seem very much so to me.

Comment: @RobNeuhaus IMO yes, it is requiring less than all pairs, but it still imposes some ordering. I am not 100% sure that the problems of `Pai_{i,j>i} P(arr[i]<arr[j])` and `Pai_{i} P(arr[i]<arr[i+1])` are completely equivalent, but intuitively they are both 'forcing' ordering, and it seems to me that the first one is at least as hard as the 2nd one (note that the 2nd one is a part of the multiplication of the first one).

Comment: After looking some more at the problem, I agree that it is intractable. I can think of no other way to find the optimal solution than calculating the probability for every permutation, and the number of permutations simply grow way too fast.

Comment: Even under a model where you are optimizing all pairs, the problem is NP-hard, as its a instance of weighted feedback arc set.  http://cs.brown.edu/~ws/papers/fast_conf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way for this is to push the elements in a priority queue. Using these 3 probabilities the one with the highest probability to be the biggest is always on top. Pop that and the next highest floats up. Continue popping until you finish. I think this approach would work

Comment: Pretty sure this greedy approach fails similarly to why it fails on TSP. Working on a reduction.

Comment: @amit: Yes, I think you are right. We are actually looking for a permutation with the highest sum of log-probabilities.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Not exactly, will add an answer in a second explaining why a very similar problem (easier) is TSP (working on it now).

Comment: @amit:I don't see why it needs to be complicated.If we use the probabilities as weights while comparing each 2 elements then we can implement the 1/-1/0 for the comparison for P(A>B)>P(B>A) etc

Comment: @Cratylus Because you have no guarantee that if `P(A<B)>P(A>B)` and `P(B<C)>P(B>C)` then `P(A<C)>P(A>C)`. this is called transitive relation and is essential for sorting.